# Looping through an image directory

Tags: php

I need to loop through a .png image directory and insert the file name in a mysql database.

This is what I have so far:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'admin', '');
mysql_select_db('database');

// Each file is formated like this
$file = 'Abe+Froman+SK_HG.png';

$player_name = urldecode(str_replace("_HG.png", "", $file));
//echo $player_name;

mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO signatures SET gamertag = '".$player_name."'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [opendir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) to open a directory and [readdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) to loop through it:

```
<?php
// From the manual entry for opendir
$dir = "/etc/php5/";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            //Do your sql insert - the filename is in the $file variable
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This will catch everything, including the `.` and `..` directories, which is not exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it is with [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) which allows you to select only the png images if other files are also present in the same directory.

```
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    $player_name = urldecode(str_replace("_HG.png", "", $filename));
    mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO signatures SET gamertag = '".$player_name."'");
}
```